# !Regex.IsMatch is not working in window form using csharp

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio

I am applying regex on my window form using c#. but regular expression on field is not working

```
if (txtRefno.Text == "" && !Regex.IsMatch(txtRefno.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
{
    msg.Text = "reference no. contain Invalid characters";
}
```

but its not working and accept everything.
I changed the pattern to `"^[0-9]+$"` but same result I receive; then I changed the condition of `regex.IsMatch(inputstring, pattern) == false;` then error should be displayed, but it also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't help you with the Regex epression as I'm not very strong on that but I think you should replace the AND with an OR in your if statement to allow the compiler to check the regex in the case the textbox is not empty.

```
if (txtRefno.Text.trim() == string.Empty || !Regex.IsMatch(txtRefno.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
{
    msg.Text = "reference no. contain Invalid characters";
}
```

or if you don't want show the message in the case the texbox is empty you can use the below

```
if (txtRefno.Text.trim() != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(txtRefno.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
    {
        msg.Text = "reference no. contain Invalid characters";
    }
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` might be better for the first test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your regular expression, but in the first part of your boolean expression. There is no sence in comparing the empty string. Change this to

txtRefno.Text != ""